# Expected value of a sample median from a sample of size $\sqrt{n}$ taken from a set of $n$ numbers

Tags: probability, statistics, median

I am stuck at the following problem: given $n$ numbers I uniformly sample $\sqrt{n}$ of them (at once) and take the sample median $X_m$. How does it correspond to the real median $n/2$? In more detail, what is $\mathbb{E}(X_m)$? Perhaps there is a nice way to show it is "near" the real median (I hope it is).

I can't really come up with some nice formula that I can solve besides some combinatorial expressions that define $\mathbb{P}(X_m = k)$ where I count the number of sets that would yield a median $k$.

Comment: Assuming the set is $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ then the median of the set and the expected median of the sample are both $\frac{n+1}{2}$; this is also the mean of the set and the expected mean of the sample, and the same sort of thing will happen with any other set with a distribution symmetric  about its centre. (You might also say whether you are sampling with or without replacement)

Comment: But is that true nothwithstanding the size of the sample? Or is it particular to $\sqrt{n}$. I am sorry if it is trivial, I do not see it yet. And I am sampling without replacement, I am choosing a subset of that size.

Comment: Any random procedure $r$ invariant in distribution under the action of the symmetry $$s:k\mapsto n+1-k$$ such as the one you are considering is bound to provide an expectation $e_r$ such that $$e_r=s(e_r)$$ that is, $$e_r=\frac n2$$

Comment: For a counterexample when the distribution is not symmetric, consider the (multi)set $\{1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2\}$; then the median of this multiset is $1$, but the expected value of the median of a three-element submultiset is obivously greater than one. (And by perturbing the samples minutely, it's easy to construct a counterexample that's a proper set as opposed to a multiset.)

Comment: *Typo in my last comment, please read: if $r$ is invariant under the action of $$s:k\mapsto n+1-k$$ then $$e_r=s(e_r)$$ hence $$e_r=\frac{n+1}2$$